# Express not working with node 9.x

Tags: node.js, express, npm

I have an `Ubuntu` box with node - v 9.5.0 and npm - 5.6.0 versions. I am trying to use `expressjs` (http://expressjs.com), but unable to run it. It works fine for node v 4.x.x.

```
$ express -h 
module.js:557
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'commander'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:555:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:482:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:604:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/nodejs/express-generator/bin/express:3:15)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
```

What is it that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu's packages seem to be outdated. 
Installing using `apt-get node-express-generator` gives this error.

Installing using `npm i -g express-generator` works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I've been googling around for over a day, uninstalling, reinstalling and updating express-generator, completely forgetting that what caused the issue in the first place was trying to use `apt-get` to install it.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to follow the preceding steps.

1. Install the [current version of NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions)
2. Uninstall all modules with `npm uninstall and rm -fr ~/.npm`
3. Reinstall `express-generator`

Hope it helps.

Comment: HtmlHint? What is the relation?

Comment: Ah, sorry. My bad, I forgot to change the name of the package.